# How to get an excel file from s3 bucket and upload the file again to s3 bucket without using pandas - Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get an excel file with s3.get_object function and upload the file back to a temp location in the s3 bucket through s3.put_object function. I do not want to use pandas library or do not want to create a pandas dataframe in between this process to do so.

The code I used so far is:

```py
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = 'mybucket'
key_obj = 'name of the file.xlsx'


file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key_obj)
file_con = file_obj.read().decode('utf-8') 
file_data = io.StringIO(file_con)


s3.put_object(file_data, Bucket=bucket, 'tmp' + '\filename.xlsx')
```

This code is not able to read the excel file properly. With this I got an error:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

when I changed the decoding from 'utf-8' to 'ISO-8859-1'. This error was dropped but the file which was written in the tmp folder was not in readable format and was not even opening up.

Pls suggest . Thanks

Comment: What `bucket = bucket` is supposed to do? Your code is invalid python, so how even you could get to any error if the code is not valid python code?

Comment: yeah there's really not enough information here . But based on what I see it seems like the only reason it even runs is that `bucket` was assigned a variable earlier that you didn't remove from the namespace. if you change it `s3.bucket` does it work?

Comment: It is an example of what I used. In reality the used a proper bucket name. In here I just wanted to show my approach.

Comment: Alright so I have edited the code to be more precise. I hope this is understandable for what I want to ask. Many Thanks

Comment: There is no way this code can produce the error you are showing. Why not provide actual, working code that is the cause of the issue?

Comment: Hang on. Do you simply want to copy an object _within_ S3? You can simply use `copy_object()` to do that, without needing to even download or get the object. Or, use `download_file()` to put a copy in `/tmp/` and then `upload_file()` to upload it. No need to read bytes from the file itself.

Comment: Hi John, This is the very first pass of the function I want to build upon. So I would need to read the bytes. That is why I need get_object and put_object operations. Do you have any suggestion please how can I use these and do the required tasks . Thank you

Comment: It worked, Thank you Marcin !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is **full of mistakes**, thus its not clear what you really want to do. But to make it a valid python code which correctly downloads and uploads a file, it should be:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'mybucket'
key_obj = 'name of the file.xlsx'

file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key=key_obj)
file_con = file_obj['Body'].read()
file_data = io.BytesIO(file_con)

s3.put_object(Body=file_data, Bucket=bucket, Key='tmp' + '/filename.xlsx')
```